# allow IPs provided by external url (in json format) in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I doubt even it is possible or not. I have a strange requirement by client so have to do.

I have a website that allow certain ips(ips are hard coded in .htaccess ). Client has provided me a url that have some ips listed in json format. I want that these ips should be allowed to access the website. (Ips listed on url are dynamic so i can't use them in .htaccess). Do anyone have idea how to achieve this.

I know i can use a php file(index) in htaccess and write code in it to read ips but the priority is to get it done by .htaccess file only.

### Thanks in advance.

Need little bit help.

I have created rewriteMap in httpd file.
RewriteMap accessmap "txt:E:\htdocs\myfolder\map.txt"

My map.txt have follwing entries.

```
127.0.0.11  allow
127.0.0.1  allow
127.0.0.12  deny
```

These entries i am adding in htacces file

```
RewriteCond ${accessmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} allow [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampleweb.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Now, for example i have 127.0.0.1  in my map file as allow so it should be allowed to access the site. If i want to access site form any other ip like
130.0.0.11 (not in map file) it should be redirect to this link https://www.exampleweb.com .

I do not have much knowledge about htaccess to can't understand how to write
rewriteRule and rewrite condition for this. Please help.
Note: Ips are just for example, actual ips will be different for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a RewriteMap. Add below code in Apache configuration file (httpd.conf) or in your virtual host file.

   ***RewriteMap accessmap "txt:file/path/to/map.txt"***

   **NOTE:** RewriteMap directive cannot be added in *.htaccess* file or inside *Directory* section. [Source: [Using rewrite map]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html)
2. Then in your *.htaccess* file add below code

   ***RewriteCond ${accessmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !^allow***

   ***RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]***

   This will allow IP addresses listed in *map.txt* file having value *allow* to access your site. Otherwise, users will see 403 forbidden error.

Comment: It is working for me. You save my life.
I have one more add on condition, I want to redirect some ips and other i want to deny. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files are constantly read by Apache HTTPD server. You can be changing the specific Authorization directives in it according to your needs by a script or something else and the new auth directives will be applied instantly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. i am doing it by rewriteMap. I have edited question and added my current status of my problem. Please go through it, it will be great if you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: edited text will be start from ..Need little bit help